# LCK_M_SCH_M Blocking

Tags: sql-server-2008, schema, blocking

I have 2 stored procedures (one vendor, one third party) that are constantly (monthly) stepping on each other.  They both (for some reason) acquire a schema lock when all they are doing is updating tables in the database.  As this is a vendor database, there is only one schema.  When these two calls occur at about the same time...down goes the database.  There is nothing I can do to kill these processes and everytime I have to recycle the SQL Server to get the system back up again.

What calls in T-SQL would force a Schema Lock?  I am skimming through the code to try and find the area that is the culprit, but nothing is jumping out at me.  Are there calls that would create a Schema Lock that you wouldn't expect would?

Also...should 2 different calls be able to acquire a Schema Lock at the same time?  I can say with great confidence that everytime this happens, it's when these two SP's are called within a second of each other.

Comment: Posting the stored procedures may help instead of us guessing at what may cause the locking.

Comment: Its difficult to answer unless you post codes of SP. Schema locks are SCM-M ( modification) and SCH-S(stability) which one you are talking about. Alter table command takes schema modification locks, there are others as well

Comment: Why do you have to recycle the SQL Server? You state you can't kill the processes, but I'm assuming you can see the queries using something like sp_whoisactive? What does sql report for the wait resource? I agree with +johnm, the procs themselves would be helpful to see.

Comment: I can see the queries with sp_WhoIsActive but using the kill command on the SPID does not work in this situation.  (50708ms)LCK_M_SCH_M is what I get for the wait_info.  I will look to post the code.  The one thing I did see in the code was that they were creating indexes on temp tables.  Are those stored in temp db or do those get stored in the database the procedure is called from?

Comment: If you are using `sp_WhoIsActive` you can add `get_plans=1` to try and pull the execution plan for the command.